# Using forms authentication in console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, configuration, console-application

I have a slightly odd situation whereby I have a C# framework 4.6.2 console application to run background tasks that use a shared library for authentication.

Authentication is important here because there are downstream HTTP API dependencies that require a cookie.

The shared authentication project uses `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)` to create a cookie, however, the `FormsAuthentication` methods require that you have the appropriate setup in a `Web.config` file.

In my console app, I only have an `app.config` file and if I add the `<authentication>` and `<machinekey>` elements they do not appear to be picked up by `FormsAuthentication`.

Unfortunately for me, I am unable to make any wholesale changes to this stack as it is a large legacy application with many dependencies, all with an assumption that forms auth will "just work".

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some of the code that performs the actual connection? Have you tried debugging it, and investigating the various objects involved? Perhaps you can add / set the missing values programmatically, instead of relying on any config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was mistaken as to the cause of this problem. I can confirm that the forms authentication settings are indeed taken from the `app.config`, however, the problem was with the default compatibility mode of the machine key element.

After reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.machinekeysection.compatibilitymode?view=netframework-4.8) article I realised that the console application was defaulting to `Framework20SP1` but the web API at the other end was defaulting to `Framework45`.

I will leave this answer here in case anyone else has similar issues - if so check the compatibility mode being used in each service. If (like me) you need to override the default so that they match between services then simply add the `compatibilityMode="Framework45"` attribute to the `<machineKey>` element.